# how to get authenticated user on API side

Tags: amazon-web-services, rust, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use the amazon provided crates to get the authenticated user for the current request.

```
let region_provider = RegionProviderChain::default_provider()
    .or_else("us-east-1");
let config = aws_config::from_env().region(region_provider).load().await;
let cognito = aws_sdk_cognitoidentityprovider::Client::new(&config);
```

This code doesn't compile, saying that the aws_sdk_cognitoidentityprovider::Client constructor requires a type of SdkConfig. I have searched far and wide but couldn't find a way of constructing this SdkConfig type. Can someone help?

Exact error:

```
    mismatched types
expected reference `&aws_types::sdk_config::SdkConfig`
   found reference `&aws_config::Config`rustcE0308
main.rs(14, 19): arguments to this function are incorrect
client.rs(12040, 12): associated function defined here
```

Comment: Not an expert on rust, however, this document -> https://docs.rs/aws-sdk-config/latest/aws_sdk_config/struct.Client.html Indicates there may be another layer of abstraction on top of aws_config,  being aws_sdk_config.

Comment: let client = aws_sdk_config::Client::new(&shared_config); It just creates a client for aws. Funnily enough, aws_sdk_config::Config::new waits an &SdkConfig and create a Config from it. I still dont understand how to instantiate the SdkConfig object. Sadly some of the documentation is confusing because I have seen in the crates SdkConfig has been renamed to Config to make it harder to research......

Comment: If you're still seeing this issue, could you post your cargo.toml? (or just the aws_* dependencies). That should compile, but there's a chance you have mismatched deps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone wondering the way to instantiate the SdKConfig struct is:
let sdkConfig = aws_types::sdk_config::SdkConfig::builder().build();